# haproxy close connecton after 1 minute

Tags: haproxy

this config

```
frontend https_frontend
bind *:4055
mode tcp
maxconn 8192
use_backend https_web

backend https_web
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option http-keep-alive
server haproxy2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4055 send-proxy-v2
```

new connection send keep-alive packets every 30 seconds. but connection drop after 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're using `mode tcp`, but `option http-keep-alive` is a `mode http` option.  In this case, it would most likely be using whatever value you have for `timeout client` or `timeout server` before dropping the connection.

For more details about `option http-keep-alive` and `mode http`, see:

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/7-5/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-modes/#http-modes-in-haproxy

Answer (score 0):

```
    frontend https_frontend
    bind *:4055
    mode tcp
    maxconn 8192
    use_backend https_web

    backend https_web
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    timeout client 600000
    timeout server 600000
    server haproxy2 147.78.65.172:4055 send-proxy-v2
```

now i send keep-alive packets and real data every 30 seconds

but steel drop after 2 minutes

its not http/https query. its sample tcp communication with rand data. maybe it problem?